# Converting SVG with custom Fonts to PNG using Inkscape

Tags: linux, svg, png, converters, inkscape

I have problem when try to convert SVG to PNG use Inkscape, the SVG file contain custom font that not available in my machine(Linux).

SVG File:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61378613/source_file.svg

Here the command to convert into PNG:

> sudo inkscape -z -e result.png -w 3750 -h 7350 -d 3028 source_file.svg

Here there result when use inkscape:
[image]

this is the result open in browser:
[image]

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`?  If you installed your fonts only for your current user, `root` will not have those fonts, and that would be the cause of your problem.

Comment: ok, please skip sudo for now, actually same result though without use 'sudo'.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the font on the system, inkscape can't guess glyphs shapes of a font it has no access to.

The browser is living in the network, so it cheats by downloading web fonts in the background (and not making them available to other apps, that's web fonts main weakness)

Comment: This.  This is correct, I've misread the question when i added my comment to it.  @nim - maybe you could add a quick note about `fc-list` and `fc-cache`, might be useful when someone finds this question by searching.